# jquery angularjs how to know if mouse down event is trigger by scrollbar of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have a small panel which i close if mouse down button is pressed anywhere else than that panel, basically it clears the data to display and just with the help of angularjs ng-show i hide it if there is no data...application is in angularjs and jquery

please find the code below

```
 var closeSearchResultsIfClickedOutside = function (e) {

    if ($(e.target).parents('.searchResults').length === 0) {
        var scope = angular.element($("#searchContainer")).scope();
        scope.$apply(function () {

            /*Cancels any existing search*/
            if ($scope.defer != undefined) {
                $scope.defer.resolve();
            }

            $scope.showSearchResults = false;
            reinitialize();                
        });

        $("html").off("mousedown", closeSearchResultsIfClickedOutside);

        reinitializePanelsWidth();
    }      
};
```

but i dont want to close this panel if mouse down is on scrollbar of browser window or any scrollbar..please tell me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

to fix the above problem i am not capturing both event, mouse down and click, if the target element on both event matches then only i am closing the panel.

```
 /*
  If mouse down and click on the same control, then only close the panel,
  Click event closing is added to avoid closing panel on scrollbar click.  
*/
var closeSearchResultsIfClickedOutside = function (e) {

    if (e.type === 'mousedown') { /* only if mouse down is outside of search panel then only close the panel. */
        if($(e.target).parents('.searchResults').length === 0)
        {
            isMouseDownOnSearchPanel = true;
        }
    else {
            isMouseDownOnSearchPanel = false;
        }
    }
    else if (e.type === 'click' && isMouseDownOnSearchPanel) {  /*click event is implemented to avoid closing when mouse down is on scrollbar. you dont get click get event for scrollbar*/
        var scope = angular.element($("#searchContainer")).scope();

        $("html").off("mousedown", closeSearchResultsIfClickedOutside);
        $("html").off("click", closeSearchResultsIfClickedOutside);
        isMouseDownOnSearchPanel = false;

        reinitializePanelsWidth();
    }       
};
```